# Problem moving gear lever when shifting

Tags: gears, yamaha

I've got a Yamaha TTR 125 LE that is having problems shifting from 2nd to 1st (down shifting). It's kinda like you have to pump brakes on a car.I have to push down on the shifter multiple times for it to engage and sometimes when I shift down it will get stuck in between gears and act like it is in neutral.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!